# How to remove duplicates in a string

Tags: excel-formula

I have a file contains 38,000 records each row contains 2 or more ';' at the end. is there any formula to remove the end repeated ';' in Excel or any other tool for example

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: You can search and replace `;` in excel

Comment: Use a regular expression replacement. Replace `;+$` with `;`

Answer (score 1):

## To remove repeated characters <sub><sup>(semi-colons in this case)</sup></sub>

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. **Find What:** `;;`  (two semicolons)
3. **Replace with:** `;` (one semicolon)
4. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.
   When it finishes, repeat Step 4 until there are no more matches found.

Now the document will have no more than one semicolon in a row.

---

## Remove repeated characters using a VBA function:

The following function does the same thing using VBA, and for any character you choose:

```
Function removeDoubleChars(txt As String, doubleChar As String) As String
'removes all multiple-consecutive [doubleChar] within [txt]
    Do
        txt = Replace(txt, doubleChar & doubleChar, doubleChar)
    Loop While InStr(txt, doubleChar & doubleChar) > 0
    removeDoubleChars = txt
End Function
```

You would use this like `Range("A1") = removeDoubleChars ( Range("A1"), ";")` to remove consecutive semicolons from cell `A1`.